# What is the Default Location of Photos in Photo application?

Tags: macos, email, photos, web-app

I see many photos in Photos application. 
However, I cannot add them to my mails without knowing their exact location.
I am using El Capitan.
Of course, I can take a screenshot of originals always but I see this as a way of duplicating things, losing accuracy and causing trash.

I would like to get the location for the internet browser like Google Chrome, Firefox, ...

You cannot drag and drop directly from Photos to the SE's picture uploader neither.

---

How can you add a photo in Photos application to a web email window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the photo > Share > Mail

[image]

Alternatively, from within Mail itself
Window menu > Photo Browser

[image]

Comment: In what browser? I added how to do it directly from Mail.

Comment: You mean you use some kind of webmail setup? Then you should have specified that in your question... & the answer will then be, drag the photo from Photos to the desktop & then attach it.

Comment: I've never tried directly to a file-picker & I don't use webmail to be able to test. You can't drag directly to SE's picture uploader though, I can test that. Photos does a good job of keeping the user out of the file hierarchy, which is why it's just simpler to drag to the desktop first.

Comment: You cannot drag-and-drop directly to the SE's image uploader neither.

Comment: Yes, I already tested & commented to that effect.